# quickly calculate a point of intersection over two arithmetic progressions

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, math

Progression A follows this rule:
Each value is all the odd values summed together up to and including N sub i .

N sub 4.
`1+3+5+7 = 16`

Progression B follows this rule.
Take the ceiling of the square root times 2 plus 1.  Subtract N from the ceiling tines itself.  Continue to add odd numbers.

N =33.
Ceiling(√33) =6.
6*2+1=13.
36-33=3.
3+13 =16.

Stop as 16 is in both progression A and B.  Is it possible to do this quickly?   I.e. a minimal 1 or 2 step solution?  A java or general implementation would be handy

**question **

`What is the output you desire? Simply abool saying they do meet? Or do you want the indices at which they do meet, i.e.A[4]=16 andB[17]=16? Or do you just want the number at which they meet, i.e.16? And what if they don't meet exactly? Do you want the indices (or number) before, or after, the intersection? Finally, when or how do you decide to halt, if, say, the two sequences will never meet? (I know in this case they do, but I mean in the general case.)`

The output i am expecting would be the value 16 or it could be the index that B finds the value as both are equivalent as the index is just the ith term.  If they dont meet i realize it is a non terminating program.  This scenario I don't care about.

Comment: What is the output you desire? Simply a `bool` saying they _do_ meet? Or do you want the indices at which they _do_ meet, _i.e._ `A[4]=16` and `B[17]=16`? Or do you just want the number at which they meet, _i.e._ `16`? And what if they don't meet exactly? Do you want the indices (or number) before, or after, the intersection? Finally, when or how do you decide to halt, if, say, the two sequences will never meet? (I know in this case they do, but I mean in the general case.)

Comment: @acheong87. Updated my post to reply to you

Comment: What is it that you plan to generalize? Obviously you know the solution to this already: `16`. Is "Progression B" what will change in your next program?

Comment: "Arithmetic progression" is a mathematical term with strictly defined meaning. What you describe in your question are not arithmetic progressions.

Comment: @acheong87. Ah yes progression B will be the piece that changes.  And subsequently progression A will be be the same every time insofar that it always starts at 1.

Comment: @andreyt i could have sworn i saw a paper stating that the squares are a progression.  Please enlighten me what needs to change to be mathematically correct.

Comment: From your clarifications, I believe your problem can be simplified to, "Efficiently finding the first perfect square in a sequence." Would you agree? If so, I would visit [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Try pasting my following comment in the question box; I've started you out on the LaTeX version of your question.

Comment: And here's the LaTeX: `\begin{align} o_k &= 2k-1 \\ A_n &= \sum_{k=1}^{n}{o_k} = n^2 \\ B_n &= \lceil\sqrt{o_n}\rceil^2 + 2\lceil\sqrt{o_n}\rceil - o_n + 1 \end{align}`. Good luck!

Comment: @Woot4Moo: `1, 3, 5, 7, ...` is an arithmetic progression. The sequence of partial sums of this arithmetic progression is `1, 4, 9, 16, ...`, which gives you squares. However, the sequence of squares by itself is not an arithmetic progression. Moreover, it is not a "progression". Traditionally there are three kinds of progressions in mathematics: arithmetic, geometric and harmonic. A sequence of squares does not belong to any of these.

Comment: @acheong87 hmm i dont know if that would actually hold.  But if it does then one could assume if we know the rate at which squares grow we could do this efficiently?  Or am I way off base?

Comment: @andreyt ah thanks.  It is always good to learn the correct terminology.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - I could be misunderstanding. But see, you basically want to alter "Progression B", and find the first integer at which the sequence "meets" a number in "Progression A". But as others have pointed out, "Progression A" is the sequence of integer squares. So really, you're looking for the first integer that is a square. If I'm misunderstanding, which is possible, a counterexample would help me understand best. OTOH, if you agree, then you're not off-base at all! The optimization would indeed _depend_ on something to do with properties of squares, _e.g._ their known rate of growth.

Comment: @acheong87 thanks.  I will move this there tomorrow when more people will be around.  If you can think of anything in the interim I am all ears.

Comment: @acheong87 it would appear that is what I am looking for.  So it seems that i need to figure out a rate of growth.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - One more thing I just realized, that may be crucial. Another way of looking at your problem is this. Realize that sequences can be seen as functions, _i.e._ `A(x)` and `B(x)`. What you want to know is the minimal "zero" of `B(x) - A(x)= 0`! And we know `A(x) = x^2`, so you need an algorithm to efficiently compute the minimal zero of `B(x) - x^2 = 0`. Take a look at [root-finding algorithms here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm). I recall using "fixed-point iteration" and "secant methods" for such problems, but I've never had to find _minimum_ zeroes...

Comment: @acheong87 hmm this looks very familiar but i can't quite put my finger on it. I now wonder if this is going to blow the complexity out.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Well, there is a reason these algorithms exist, and that's because they're fast. By their names they may sound scary, but some of them are rather simple to implement. The thing is, I don't know how well they behave when discreet functions (`ceil`) are thrown in. For example, many of these algorithms require differentiability. If you ask math.stackexchange.com, I'm sure the folks there will give you much, much more help than I can, and probably come here and downvote my answer out of the water for making inaccurate statements.

Comment: @acheong87 the help is appreciated.  If it is computationally easy to get the solution all the better.  A heuristic approach seems to be a solid way to approach this problem, basrd on my readings so far.

Answer (score 4):

I'll summarize my comments here so it's easier to understand for new visitors.

As others have pointed out, *Sequence A* is merely a sequence of squares; and as OP clarified through his comments, *Sequence B* will be ever-changing.

A restatement of OP's problem might be

**Is there a faster way to determine the first square in an increasing sequence, than computing each term of the sequence?**

Indeed, there is. The obvious idea is to devise a way to "skip" the computation of some terms, based on insight regarding the rates of growth of squares, versus the sequence. But it will be hard to programmatically derive insight about an arbitrary sequence.

A more robust solution might be to reformulate the problem as finding the smallest zero of:

```
B(x) - x^2 = 0
```

And for that, there may exist [root-finding algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) that may help. If you don't need to find the *smallest* zero, then even easier: implement any root-finding algorithm, watch the algorithm converge to a zero, add `x^2` to compensate for the reformulation, and there you have it.

---

**EDIT**

(The comment box was too limited to reply to yours.)

When I said "bisection", I actually meant "binary search". This requires an upper bound, so doesn't really apply to your problem.

Let me offer a naive algorithm though, as a start, although you've probably already thought exactly this.

1. Compute `B(1)`. Say it's `1692` (not a square).
2. Compute `B(2)`. Say it's `1707` (not a square).
3. Compute `B(2)-B(1)`, call it the "delta", *e.g.* `1707-1692`, or `15`. Consider this a *naive* estimation of the rate of growth of `B`. It's almost definitely wrong, of course, but all we're aiming for here is *some way to skip terms*. That's what's to be optimized, later.
4. What's the next square greater than `1707`? A formula, `(floor(sqrt(1707))+1)^2`, yields `1764`.
5. How many terms should we skip to try to reach that square? Another formula, `(1764-1707)/15`, yields `3.8`, which we might round to `4`.
6. Compute `B(2+4) = B(6)`.

   1. If *smaller* than `1764`, then you need to keep going. But you've saved, in this case, having to compute 3 terms. Exactly how you choose to keep going, is just another choice. You can compute `B(7)` and go to step 3 (computing `B(7)-B(6)` as a new delta). You can go directly to step 3 (computing `(B(6)-B(2))/4` as a new delta). (You can't really know what's best without *characterizing* the possible functions for `B`.)
   2. If *larger* than `1764`, then you need to go back. Again, there's many ways. Binary search is actually a simple, reasonable way. Compute `B(4)` since it's directly in between `B(2)` and `B(6)`. If less than `1764`, try `B(5)`. If greater than `1764`, try `B(3)`. If either don't match, then carry on starting with `B(7)`. With binary search, at most you'll do `log(N)` computations.

So that sounds like a good deal, right? You'll either skip a number of computations, or you'll do `log(N)` at most. (Or, you'll find even better optimizations to this.) But, obviously, it's not that simple, because you're doing extra computations to find these deltas, projections, binary search, etc. Since squares grow very slowly (there's only so many integers between squares), I feel such an algorithm will only beat the "linear search" (computing every term) if you're dealing with large integers, or extremely complex sequences of `B` (but given that `B` has to always increase, how complex can a sequence really be?) The key would be to find a *characterization* that fits all your sequences, and capitalize on *that* by finding an optimization specific to it.

I still don't know what your application is, but at this point you might as well just try it and benchmark it (versus linear search) over realistic datasets. This would immediately tell you whether there's any practical gain, and whether more time should be invested in optimization. And it'll be faster than trying to do all the theoretical math, characterizing sequences and whatnot.

Comment: Not sure about the "monotonically increasing sequence"... in fact, the second sequence mentioned in the question (33 -> 16) is not monotonical.

Comment: @ft1 - Oops, I used a fancy word without thinking; thanks, edited.

Comment: Hmm could i use the bisection method on this or am i misunderstanding the function.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - To summarize my edit, a naive algorithm would be to (1) project, and (2a) continue or (2b) bisect. (I learned that "bisection" actually may be a valid term for this, after all.)

Answer (score 1):

FYI, your first sequence is simply the squares.

It should be clear that both sequences are monotonically increasing. Therefore, all you need to do is keep an index into each sequence and repeatedly increment whichever index points to a smaller number, until both indices point to the same number.

Note that if the sequences have no numbers in common, this will run forever.

Comment: I understand it would run forever.  My question is more along the lines of how can i determine where that overlap occur and how I could calculate that point without checking every point.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm in pseudocode:

```
int i=1, j=1;
int x=func1(i), y=func2(j);
while x!=y {
  if x<y {i++; x=func1(i)}
  else   {j++; y=func2(j)}
}
```

Assuming all that we know is that `func1` and `func2` are increasing functions, it's difficult to optimize this algorithm further.

Comment: I think he's aware of the basic algorithm, but he's looking for an optimization. Rewording the problem to, "Efficiently finding the first perfect square in a sequence," I don't think hope is lost that there may be a better way.

Comment: What's inefficient about a linear-time algorithm?  I don't see how you can find points of intersection without having values to compare.  Maybe this algorithm is slow but if there isn't a more efficient solution then that would make this the most efficient possible solution, right?

Comment: I'm not really saying your solution is inefficient; I'm just saying OP's looking for something faster. I'm not sure what makes you so sure there isn't a more efficient solution. When you know certain unique properties of a problem, you're often able to optimize using that specific knowledge, sacrificing generality. For example, when you know that a list is sorted, then suddenly you can use bisection (not sure this is the correct term) to find, say, whether a number exists in the list, _i.e._ without comparing every value. Similarly, the properties of squares may lead to something here.